# iOS multiline UIButon touch not working

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I saw that the button is not resized when having multiple lines, but only the text comes out of the button area, which leads to the `TouchUpInside` event being triggered only when the tap was inside the button, not on the text outside the button.

How can I resize the button depending on the text?

If I set the height constraint to be `GreaterThanOrEqual` it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the button's frame to be equal to it's title label's frame, after view did layout. e.g.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let originalFrame = btn.frame
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: originalFrame.origin.x,
                       y: originalFrame.origin.y,
                       width: originalFrame.width,
                       height: btn.titleLabel!.frame.height)
}
```

Or set the button's height constraint to this value:

```
btn.titleLabel!.frame.height)
```